# Java unit test with common code

Tags: java, java-8

I am new to Java so apologies in advance if this is a silly question.

I noticed that I'm writing redundant code as my test cases are testing similar behavior with different attributes of same object.

```
@Test
public void testInvalidA() {
    obj.setA(null)
    //verify exception thrown if A is null
}

@Test
public void testInvalidB() {
    obj.setB(null)
    //verify exception thrown if B is null
}
```

Is there a way that I could simplify this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but please don't.  Keep your tests clear and expressive.  A small amount of duplication is acceptable in a test class; but feel free to refactor if the duplicated chunk is more than a few lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use assertj. Example code would be like this,

```
@Test
public  void testObjectsAreValid() {
    assertThatExceptionOfType(ExpectedException.class)
        .isThrownBy(obj.setA(null);
    assertThatExceptionOfType(ExpectedException.class)
        .isThrownBy(obj.setB(null);
}
```

assertj provides direct methods for some common exceptions.

```
assertThatIllegalArgumentException().isThrownBy(() -> obj.setB(null));
```

Check [here](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html) for more documentation.
I agree with Dawood though, keep each test separate and clear.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the way you were doing it -- in fact its preferable most of the time.  But if your example is a simplification of complexity that repeats with a similar testable signature, you could try a bit of functional programming:

```
private void nullNotAllowed( Consumer<Object> method ) {
    try {
        method.accept( null );
        fail( "Null Not Allowed");
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) { /*pass*/ }
}

@Test public void nonNullableSetters() {
    YourClass subject = new YourClass();
    nullNotAllowed( subject::setA );
    nullNotAllowed( subject::setB );
}
```

Comment: The Java-8 way of testing. Nice!